# What is the necessary condition for two integrals of a product of two functions with one common function to be equal?

Tags: calculus

for example:

$$I := \int_0^\infty f(x)h(x)\,\mathrm dx,\quad\text{and}\quad J := \int_0^\infty g(x)h(x)\,\mathrm dx$$ with $I$ and $J$ convergent.

My guess is that f(x) = g(x)

Comment: To begin with, you have to rule out some trivial cases, such as $h(x)=0$.

Comment: Pointwise equality of $f$ and $g$ is sufficient, but it is not necessary.  Consider, for example, $f \equiv 1$ on the closed ray $[0,\infty)$, and $g\equiv 1$ on the open ray $(0,\infty)$, but $g(0) = 0$.  Equality ``almost everywhere'' is, I think, the condition you want.

Comment: Your guess is wrong. Let h be the constant function and f be a shifted version of g. Where g is non zero on some finite interval over which you integrate. If f has it's non zero part in your integration interval, this will be a counter example.

Answer (score 2):

That is certainly a *sufficient* condition, but it is very far from *necessary*. Consider for example

$$ h(x) = 1 \\
f(x) = e^{-x} \\
g(x) = \tfrac12 e^{-x/2} $$

Comment: Is there a necessary condition?

Comment: In general, for any par of functions $F(x), G(x)$ with $\lim_{x\to\infty} F(x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)$ and $F(0)=G(0)$, we can choose $f(x)=F'(x)$, $g(x)=G'(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

For a fixed $h$, $f(x) = g(x)$ is not necessary. If you want it for all $h\in L^2(0,\infty)$ to be true, you actually require $f=g$ in the $L^2$-sense:

$$0 = I-J = \int_0^\infty (f(x)-g(x))h(x) d x\quad \forall h\in L^2(0,\infty).$$
This is equivalent to saying that $f-g\in (L^2(0,\infty))^\perp = \{0\}$. Therefore $f=g$ in $L^2(0,\infty)$.

Note that we have to make some specifications on the regularity of the functions here, $L^2$ is a natural choice here.

Answer (score 0):

Let $F,G$ be any primitives of $f\cdot h,g\cdot h$, respectively. Then, a necessary condition is:
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)-F(0)=\lim_{x\to\infty}G(x)-G(0)$$

Admittedly, this is nothing else than the definition of improper integral slightly disguised.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail how this implies $I=J$?

Comment: @DominikS True, I assumed $h=1$.